# Show the stock counter in more than one place on the same page

Tags: javascript, countdown

This script works great as a stock countdown, but I couldn't show it in more than 1 place on the same page.

For example, on the same page there are 4 or 5 products/plans and each product shows a different stock quantity and changing the quantity at different times from each other. Only shows on 1 product.

```
<span class="qty" id="qty"></span>

<script>
    const setQty = (qty) => {
        qtySpan.innerHTML = qty;

        if (qty == 0) return;

        let parts = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
        if (parts > qty) parts = qty;

        const msec =  Math.floor(((Math.random() * 15) + 15) * 1000);
        qty -= parts;

        // Save the updated quantity in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('saved_countdown', qty);

        setTimeout(() => setQty(qty), msec);
    }

    // Get the saved countdown value from localStorage, or use default value of 57 if not found
    const defaultQty = localStorage.getItem('saved_countdown') ?? 57;
    
    const qtySpan = document.getElementById('qty');

    // Set the initial value of the quantity
    setQty(defaultQty);
</script>
```

I duplicated the script 4x changing the ID "qty" by qty1, qty2, qty3 and qty4, but it didn't work, it keeps showing only in 1 product... :/

Would anyone here be able to help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your script into a Custom Element. This means that you can now create an element called `<stock-counter>`.

This element has 2 attributes, `quantity` and `storage-key`.

1. `quantity` is the amount to start counting from.
2. `storage-key` is the name of the Local Storage key that is used to store the last quantity of *this* specific counter. If a storage key is set and a stored value has been found, then this value will supersede the `quanitity` value, unless the stored value is `0`.

So the element would look like this:

```html
<stock-counter quantity="40" storage-key="countdown-one">40</stock-counter>
```

You can place as many of these elements on your page and modify the `quantity` and `storage-key` for each one.

```js
customElements.define('stock-counter', class extends HTMLElement {
  get quantity() {
    // Check if value has been stored.
    if (this.storageKey !== null) {
      const value = Number(localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey));

      // Use that value if it is a valid number and not 0.
      if (!Number.isNaN(value) && value !== 0) {
        return value;
      }
    }

    // Otherwise get the value from the quantity attribute.
    const value = Number(this.getAttribute('quantity'));

    if (Number.isNaN(value)) {
      return 0;
    }

    return value;
  }

  set quantity(value) {
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
    
      // Store the new value if it's possible.
      if (this.storageKey !== null) {
        localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, value);
      }

      // Set the new attribute value.
      this.setAttribute('quantity', value);
    }
  }

  get storageKey() {
    return this.getAttribute('storage-key');
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.count();
  }

  count = () => {
    const qty = this.quantity;
    this.textContent = qty;

    if (qty === 0) {
      return;
    }

    let parts = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

    if (parts > qty) {
      parts = qty;
    }

    this.quantity -= parts;

    const msec = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 15) + 15) * 1000);
    setTimeout(this.count, msec);
  };
});
```

```html
<stock-counter quantity="40" storage-key="countdown-one">40</stock-counter>
<stock-counter quantity="50">50</stock-counter>
<stock-counter quantity="80" storage-key="countdown-three">80</stock-counter>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @emiel-zuurbier, exactly what I needed. I have a question, currently, whenever you reload the page, the countdown changes immediately, without respecting the default change time. Is there a line of code I can add for the countdown to just change to its default time, regardless of reloading the page?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't understand what you mean with *default change time*.

Answer (score 0):

I change the function so you can have multiple countdown.

```
const setQty = (qtySpan, qty) => {
qtySpan.innerHTML = qty;

if (qty == 0) return;

let parts = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
if (parts > qty) parts = qty;

const msec = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 15) + 15) * 1000);
qty -= parts;

// Save the updated quantity in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('saved_countdown', qty);

setTimeout(() => setQty(qty), msec);
}

const defaultQty = localStorage.getItem('saved_countdown') ?? 57;

let listOfQty = document.querySelectorAll('.qty');
listOfQty.forEach((qty) =>{
    setQty(qty, defaultQty);

})
```

You only need to send the specific number for each count down as second argument.

Comment: Do note that every counter updates the same `saved_countdown` key in local storage.

Comment: Thanks @EmielZuurbier, but I couldn't get it to work. My level of knowledge in Javascript is still very low. Could you please show me how the final code would look like to show the counter in more than 1 place on the same page please?